# jquery .unload problem in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have the following code that works flawlessy in FF, but in IE I get an error that says "invalid property value"

The code in questions is as follows:

```
pageOpen = new Date();

dropper = new Image();

$(window).unload(function() {

  pageClose = new Date();

  sionara = (pageOpen.getTime() - pageClose.getTime())/-1000;

  dropper.src = "http://redacted.domain.com/1/%%PAGE%%/1%%REALRAND%%@x80&XE&ABC_TimeSpent="+sionara+"_seconds&XE";

  alert("close " + sionara);

});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a few minutes to read the FAQ and the Markdown documentation (a useful synposis of which is available in the right hand margin when editing a question).

Answer (score 0):

your dropper source seems wrong. why do you have so many % and @ in it?

Comment: I don't think that should matter... it mails even if it were to just be foo.com - I think the reason it fails is because dropper.src alters the DOM within the unload function and IE doesn't like that, and I can't use ajax, because it's a call across domains... don't really know what to do